# What is the difference between an Extension and a Module?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, module

What is the difference between an **Extension** and a **Module**?

Just curious to know that what is the right term to use when we extend Magento's functionality by creating our custom code in local folder.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Extensions are simply packed modules. In other words, you extend the features and functionality of Magento by writing a module. Then you have a choice to leave it as it is or pack it up (System > Magento Connect > Package Extensions). An extension (a packed module) is then published on   [magento connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/)

Comment: Hi Qaisar Satti, How can i get you?

Comment: hi @TejabhagavanKollepara sorry don't get you?

Comment: any particular reason to contacting me?

Answer (score 13):

I wish everyone will make up their minds and use the same term.
Now we have extension, module, bundle, plugin and maybe others and it's getting silly.
Basically a module is an extension.
The only difference might be that what's in the core may not be considered extensions, but they are modules.
So `Mage_Catalog` is a module but not an extension.
`Something_Else` is a module and an extension because it's not in the core.

Comment: well said Marius.. (y)

Comment: I agree, for none core I consider the two terms to be completely interchangeable.

Comment: You can't avoid it. People come from wordpress and use the term plugin.  Devs come from Joomla and say extension...

Comment: I agree with Marius.

Comment: I always agree with Marius (and Fabian too) :)

Answer (score 13):

**Module** is the **technical term** for anything you define in `app/etc/modules`

**Extension** is the **marketing term** for published<sup>1</sup> community modules (or generally any code that extends Magento functionality and is not a theme)

Extensions usually consist of one or more modules. The ebizmarts MageMonkey extension for example comes with four actual modules that are bundled as one extension: `Ebizmarts_AbandonedCart`, `Ebizmarts_Autoresponder`, `Ebizmarts_MageMonkey` and `Ebizmarts_Mandrill`.

Themes also often come with theme specific *modules* that are not distributed separately and nobody would call them *extensions*.

---

<sup>1) be it via Magento Connect, Github or an extension store</sup>