# How to create CUSTOM extension in magento 2.1.6?

Tags: magento2, extensions, custom

I was confusing among extensions and modules.

Can anyone guide me about it and i am looking for good **tutorial** for creating **extensions in magento 2.1.6**. ?

Answer (score 3):

Here are step to create the Magento2 Extension

create registration.php

app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/registration.php

```
<?php
/**
* Simple Hello World Module
*
* @category QaisarSatti
* @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
* @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti
* @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com
*
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'QaisarSatti_HelloWorld',
__DIR__
);
```

Create module.xml

app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--/**
* Simple Hello World Module
*
* @category QaisarSatti
* @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
* @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti
* @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com
*
*/ -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="QaisarSatti_HelloWorld" schema_version="0.0.1" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

Create block

app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php

```
<?php
/**
* Simple Hello World Module
*
* @category QaisarSatti
* @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
* @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti
* @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com
*
*/
namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
public function _prepareLayout()
{
parent::_prepareLayout();
$this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('First Hello World Module'));
return $this;
}
}
```

Create controller

app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
/**
* Simple Hello World Module
*
* @category QaisarSatti
* @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
* @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti
* @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com
*
*/
namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
public function execute()
{
$this->_view->loadLayout();
$this->_view->renderLayout();
}
}
```

Create frontend router

app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--/**
* Simple Hello World Module
*
* @category QaisarSatti
* @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
* @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti
* @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com
*
*/ -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
<route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
<module name="QaisarSatti_HelloWorld" />
</route>
</router>
</config>
```

Create frontend template

app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/HelloWorld.phtml

```
<?php
/**
* Catalog Product Rewrite Helper
*
* @category QaisarSatti
* @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
* @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti
* @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com
*
*/
echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

Add frontend layout handle

app/code/QaisarSatti/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--/**
* Simple Hello World Module
*
* @category QaisarSatti
* @package QaisarSatti_HelloWorld
* @author Muhammad Qaisar Satti
* @Email qaisarssatti@gmail.com
*
*/ -->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld" name="HelloWorld" template="QaisarSatti_HelloWorld::HelloWorld.phtml"></block>
</referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

You hello world module is complete .

Now run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command

Complete code on [github](https://github.com/kingsatti/Simple-HelloWorld-Module-Magneto2)

[Tutorial](http://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-create-a-module/)

Comment: thankyou Qaisar 
So can i assume that module and extensions are same ? right ?

Comment: @Funti read this for better understanding https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69849/what-is-the-difference-between-an-extension-and-a-module/69850#69850

Comment: i followed the above example but i am getting these issues

RuntimeException: Can't create directory /var/www/html/magento2.0/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/. in /var/www/html/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:115 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35):

Comment: @Funti this is permission error kindly give 777 permission to folders.

Comment: Mentiond error are removed. Should i access my created module like this
[ROOT]/helloworld ?

I tried , it says 404 Not found page

Comment: @Funti did you run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** and module is shown in list?

Comment: just run the upgrade command and all is blank now and getting 500 internal error in the console

Comment: @Funti can you share the error?

Comment: Now i have resolved all errors all are fine expect the module accessing
magento project is accessing fine ,but when i access the root/helloworld its only a blank page

Comment: your email please ?

Comment: @Funti you can find it here https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/24541/qaisar-satti?tab=profile